# Core Data / SwiftUI - How to get from a backgroundContext back to the mainContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to use concurrency to perform some expensive core data fetch request in background.

To do so I created a backgroundContext with `.newBackgroundContext()` and `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`

I'm not able to work in the main context with the data I fetched in the backgroundContext. Otherwise the app crashes.
Although the two contexts get synced it seems like I'm bound to the backgroundContext as long as I work with that fetched data, is that right?

And If so, is there any reason why not to perform everything across the whole app in the backgroundContext? That would prevent from accidentally switch to the mainContext.

Or is there any convenient way to get to the mainContext after fetching and processing the data in the backgroundContext?

Here is a small example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    let bgContext = PersistenceController.shared.container.newBackgroundContext()
    
    @State var items: [Item] =  []
    
    

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(date, formatter: itemFormatter)
            }
        }
        .task {
            items = await fetchItems(context: bgContext)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchItems(context: NSManagedObjectContext) async  -> [Item]  {
        
        do{
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
            request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
            return try bgContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            return[]
        }
        
    }
}
```

Right now, every further action needs to get done in the backgroundContext, including save and delete functions.

Comment: Don’t fetch from the background context when you want to use the objects in the main context is the simple answer since you are most likely making it overly complicated. Regarding syncing/merging, this is only relevant when saving changes but you are only fetching. The recommended solution for moving objects between contexts is to use the objectId’s for the objects since they are immutable but then it would still be better to directly fetch from the main context

Comment: Thanks for our reply! Yes this Question is focused on fetching but in a the real world I'd also want to save changes. Beside that I thought that Asynchronous Fetching is only possible in the backgroundContext? So it seems in that case, using the main context is not an option.

Comment: You can still perform an async fetch request on the main context

Comment: How expensive are we talking? You can add indexes to speed up fetching. Also if you use @FetchRequest it batches the requests. And faulting means it only loads rows that are on screen. Its highly unusual to say fetching is expensive. When you add more context you increase memory usage and have to deal with threading issues so best avoided.

Comment: You are right, fetchrequests are relatively low cost. We are talking about several thousand entries that also need to be processed to do further calculations, several times. In fetching relations thats quite expensive.
Your hint to use @FetchRequest is very helpful, I usually use NSFetchrequests in the ViewModel for the sake of MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Based on mlhals comment, I found a quite simple Solution.

I perform all expensive fetch requests and calculations in the background.

For the visible elements I use a @FetchRequest property wrapper.
Since it is updating automatically it updates changes made in the background context instantly. Further user actions like deleting etc. I can then proceed in the "main" context.